# C++ primer 5th edition: operator new and operator delete overloading

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator, new-expression

can someone explain to me this paragraph from C++ primer 5th edition:

> Terminology: new Expression versus operator new Function
>
> The library functions operator new and operator delete are
> misleadingly named. Unlike other operator functions, such as operator=,
> these functions do not overload the new or delete expressions. In fact, we
> cannot redefine the behavior of the new and delete expressions.
>
> A new expression always executes by calling an operator new function
> to obtain memory and then constructing an object in that memory. A delete
> expression always executes by destroying an object and then calling an
> operator delete function to free the memory used by the object.
>
> By providing our own definitions of the operator new and operator
> delete functions, we can change how memory is allocated. However, we
> cannot change this basic meaning of the new and delete operators.

I don't see a difference between `operator new` or `operator delete` and any other overloaded operator like the assignment operator `=`. So what it means "are misleadingly named"? and we all know that we don't override an expression like `fObj + fObj` but we overload the operator not the expression itself.

In fact I find this paragraph itself misleading. After all we can "abuse" any overloadable operator and from which operator `new` and `delete` so what did he mean in this paragraph? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most operators in C++ aren't bound by any explicit semantics or requirements. The only real exceptions are `operator new` and `operator delete` due to its specialized use, which is what this is referring to.

For example, lets consider `operator==`.

Even though it's *conventional* (and wise) to have this operator perform *some kind of comparison* and return a `bool` to indicate equality -- this actually isn't required by the C++ language.

In fact, it's actually entirely possible to define `operator==` to return something completely unrelated -- perhaps an `int`, a `std::string`, or something weirder like `std::tuple`. And, of course, it need not *actually* perform any comparison.

Effectively, the semantics of most operators in C++ are *weakly required* by convention, but not by the language.

This contrasts with `operator new` and `operator delete`. A `new` expression in C++ will *always start a dynamic object's lifetime* at the pointer returned by the `operator new` invocation. Whether this is `new (p) T{...}` for a placement-new expression, `new T{...}` with the global-`new` operator, or some `new(args,...) T{...}` for a custom `operator new` -- it must return *some form of pointer* to start a lifetime at for `T`.

Similarly, `delete` must end that lifetime, and call `operator delete` to release the underlying storage for that lifetime. This effectively forces semantics of `operator new` and `operator delete` to perform some form of allocation mechanism, and some form of cleanup mechanism respectively. It's not really possible to define `new` and `delete` to do something strange (as in the case of `operator==`), since the implied behavior of calling these operators will simply *break* (if it compiles at all).

This is why the quote mentions that the behavior of `operator new`/`operator delete` cannot be redefined; the basic meaning will always be fixed.

Comment: For example, you could use `operator<<` and `operator>>` to perform I/O, rather than bit-shifting. Of course, nobody sane should ever consider such a thing

Comment: Well, `->` is also an exception, and `,` cannot be overloaded.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont `operator,` can be overloaded, you should see the strange code Standard Library writers have to do to avoid possible overloads. ref - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Good point on `operator ->`  -- although this isn't quite as strict. Technically speaking, `operator->` just needs to return something that implements `->` -- which will either be a pointer _or_ a pointer-like type (like an iterator, smart pointer, etc).

Comment: Typo, was upposed to be `.`. For`->` it gets applied recursively in a wierd way